# Generic DAO for persistence and unit testing

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, derby

This is my BaseDAOImpl:

```
public class BaseDAOImpl implements GenericDAOI {
    protected Class entityClass;

    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public BaseDAOImpl(Class entityClass,EntityManager entityManager){
        this.entityClass=entityClass;
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public <ENTITY> ENTITY persist(ENTITY entity){
       EntityTransaction t=entityManager.getTransaction();
       t.begin();
       entityManager.persist(entity);
       t.commit();
       return entity;
     }

   public <ENTITY> ENTITY update(ENTITY entity){
       EntityTransaction t = entityManager.getTransaction();
       t.begin();
       ENTITY r = entityManager.merge(entity);
       t.commit();
       return r;
    }
   .... and so
}
```

And I am trying to unit test it:

```
public class BaseDAOImplTest {

    private EntityManagerFactory emFactory;
    private EntityManager em;
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BaseDAOImplTest.class
            .getName());

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        logger.info("Starting in-memory database for unit tests");

        try {

            //Creating testDB database
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:memory:TestingDB;create=true");
            logger.info("Building JPA EntityManager for unit tests");

            //Creating Entity Manager
            emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestingDB");
            em = emFactory.createEntityManager();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testPersistExcursion() {
        BaseDAOImpl baseDao = new BaseDAOImpl(Excursion.class, em);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(2013, 8, 24);
        Excursion ex1 = new Excursion(c.getTime(), 10, "Simple excursion 1", "New York", 35);
        ex1 = baseDao.persist(ex1);

        assertEquals(baseDao.findById(ex1.getId()), ex1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdateExcursion() {
        BaseDAOImpl baseDao = new BaseDAOImpl(Excursion.class, em);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(2013, 8, 24);
        Excursion ex1 = new Excursion(c.getTime(), 10, "Simple excursion 1", "New York", 35);
        ex1 = baseDao.persist(ex1);
        ex1.setDestination("Prague");
        assertEquals(baseDao.update(ex1), ex1);
    }
}
```

First test with only persist is okay. But there is problem in second test. I get error while commiting transaction. So what's wrong? Thanks

Comment: *What* error are you getting?

Comment: It would be nice if you posted the error.

Comment: I should wrote it better: "caused Error: Error while committing the transaction" and before that "javax.persistence.RollbackException".

Comment: I just wonder, if its a good idea to manage transactions in dao layer. This isnt really a unit test, but an integration test. In unit test, You would just make sure that entitymanager is called by using a mock